# Dynamically change application theme depending on android:icon

Tags: android, android-manifest, splash-screen, android-theme, android-launcher

I have integrated splash screen into my app from android manifest I gave it a newly made `SplashTheme` and whenever the `onActivityCreated` called I change it to the one that is needed. Now , in `splash.xml` file which you can see below:

```
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</item>
```

I put my launcher `ic_launcher` in the center but when the device in which the app is installed uses **round** icons the splash screen still shows the "original" icon. I know because I put here `ic_launcher` instead of `ic_launcher_round` but I would like to make this part dynamic, to recognize if the devices uses round icons put `ic_launcher_round` and the opposite.

Here is the part of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

[image]

Comment: Try to read about `Adaptive Icons` and `Circular Icons`...  https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/adaptive-icons    https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/circular-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, you cannot achieve the behavior you expect, simply because there does **not** exist an API, that would provide you whether current launcher uses round icon or a default icon.

Instead, you should construct your splash screen in a way, that is not dependent on the default launcher implementation of the device. Normally, you should have the same image regardless launcher uses round or normal icons.

Leave launcher icons aside and create a resource specifically for splash screen.